# Fit of the weekday variables in the plot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

[Plot is overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIXuO.png)

Here is my code,

```
perc2 %>% barplot(main = "Sample Observations by Day of Week and Season",
              ylab="Percentage", xlab="Season", beside=TRUE, 
              legend=rownames(perc2), 
              args.legend=c(x = "top",horiz=TRUE),
              ylim = c(0,20),
              col = brewer.pal(7, name = "RdBu"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution is to use `legend` separately as

```
perc2 %>% 
barplot(main = "Sample Observations by Day of Week and Season",
          ylab="Percentage", xlab="Season", beside=TRUE, 
          ylim = c(0,20))
legend(1,25, legend=rownames(perc2), col = brewer.pal(7, name = "RdBu"))
```

Note : use `legend(x = min(perc2$column) + 1, y = max(perc2$column) + 1,...)` instead of `1` and `25` as per your `perc2` dataset

Answer (score 0):

put cex the value you need. Like others are saying ggplot2 is a better solution

```
 perc2 %>% barplot(main = "Sample Observations by Day of Week and Season",
                  ylab="Percentage", xlab="Season", beside=TRUE, 
                  legend=rownames(perc2), 
                  args.legend=list(x = "top",horiz=TRUE,cex=0.8),
                  ylim = c(0,20),
                  col = brewer.pal(7, name = "RdBu"))
```